# How to set display time to success-message in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.2. How can I set time to redirect().

`return redirect('advertise-with-us')->with('success-message', 'Mail sent successfully');`

Thanks

Comment: I think your question needs more details on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set flash message display for certain time you need to write some jQuery code for this like below.

> View

```
@if(Session::has('success-message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success"> 
        <button type="button" 
            class="close" 
            data-dismiss="alert" 
            aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        {!! session()->get('success-message') !!} 
    </div>
@endif
```

> Script

```
$('div.alert').delay(5000).slideUp(300);
```